# PHP file not updating?

Tags: php, caching

programs I use:

- XAMPP
- visual studio code
- chrome

I reinstalled visual studio code and wanted to continue with an old project,

I want to put user data in a table with a nested foreach:

```
foreach ($users as $user){
  foreach ($user as $detail){
    print_r($detail);
}
```

When I check the website it doesn't show anything. removing the nest doesnt update anything either.
what I tried to fix it:

- Make sure I am on the correct page and the correct project
- Restart XAMPP server
- Check the page in incognito
- ctrl+f5 / f5 the page
- Edit php.ini: `opcache.revalidate_freq=0 opcache.enable=0`
- Reinstall XAMPP
- Try clasic cache killer in the chrome store
- Disable dev cache
- Try a different browser

code (I doubt it will be usefull, but if you need it, it's here):

```
<div id="content__admin-users">
                    <?php
                        $query = "SELECT ID, voornaam, achternaam, email, Administrator From User";
                        $result = $database->prepare($query);
                        try{
                            $result->execute(array());
                            $users = $result->fetchAll();
                        }catch(PDOException $e){
                            echo "Er is een fout opgetreden, error: $e";
                        }
                        foreach ($users as $user){
                            foreach ($user as $detail){
                               print_r($detail);
                        }
                    ?>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae minima repellat nulla voluptatum modi necessitatibus dolorem rerum laborum aliquam saepe quos rem, possimus placeat debitis asperiores, officiis autem odio iste.
                    </div>
```

what the website shows:
[image: website picture]

I think it has something to do with the cache because after a certain time it does update the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to save your file if you see this post..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT ID, voornaam, achternaam, email, Administrator From User";
$result = $database->prepare($query);
try{
    $result->execute();
    $users = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Er is een fout opgetreden, error: $e";
}
foreach ($users as $index => $user) {
    foreach ($user as $column => $value) {
        echo $column." : ". $value;
    }
}
// or
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($users as $index) print_r($users[$index]);
echo "</pre>";
// release PDO object.
$result = null;
?>
```

Comment: That is not the problem. the problem is that the page is not updating. I know how to change indexes etc. my page is just not updating

Comment: release pdo object. $result = null;

Comment: still doesn't update the php file for me.
If I for example delete the lorem part, it still shows the lorem

Comment: your saying that the php file was didn't updated. If someone user come in the page, Should the user's data be printed on the page? If so, either getting user's id value by get or post parameter or save data to session, and search only the user's data on query. Why you search all user's data? and print all?

Comment: no im talking about the page not changing the information thats on there.
For example if i'd change `echo "hello";` to `echo "test";` it would still print hello instead of test
the reason I want all the users is because its an admin panel